# Run Api requests with EEL on python

Tags: python, api, flask, eel

is it possible to run flask and eel together ?

for example. if i have project index.html ( assets are in assets/ ). am using EEL to make the html and python are working together. but i wanted to ask if it possible to also use API requests beside eel.

Comment: i need answer please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes here from future. i found a solution for this which is [Django-eel](https://pypi.org/project/django-eel/).

Django-Eel is a Django App for HTML GUI applications, with easy Python/JS interoperation. It is a porting version of Eel.